# Why does JavaPNS send production push messages to the sandbox server?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, javapns

Push notification works for the sandbox.

Then I create a new certificate for Push Production.

The app is in app store now.

The server code call looks like this:

```
Push.combined(message, badgeCount, DEFAULT_SOUND, KEYSTORE, KEYSTOREPASSWORD, SANDBOX, token)
```

where SANDBOX is false.

Yet, when the server, using the production P12 file, tells the JavaPNS module to send a push notification, the log looks like this:

396784 [Thread-61] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Initialized Connection to Host: [gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com] Port: [2195]: 416e43d7[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com/17.149.34.188,port=2195,localport=48070]]

It seems to use the sandbox server.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong is that the parameter to which you pass `false` is actually called `production`, which means you should pass `true` if you wish to connect to the production push env :

```
public static PushedNotifications combined(
    String message, int badge, String sound, Object keystore, String password,
    boolean production, Object devices)
  throws CommunicationException, KeystoreException
```

Comment: Lol! Thanks a bunch. I was handed this code by another developer. I didn't occur to me to check the parameters.